# Google Analytics Campaign/Source/Medium Not Showing

Tags: google-analytics

I have a "short URL" MVC website that takes in an identifier and redirects the user to the end resource based on that identifier.

Prior to the redirect I create a web request to Google Analytics (GA) to track which identifiers are commonly used. I would also like to track some more information using campaign/source/medium options in GA but I'm having a tough time getting these to show in the reports - the link I'm using is below (utmac switched out for obvious reasons):

https://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmdt=ShortUrl+Redirect&utmp=%2f3f20118&utmac=UA-9999999-99&utmcc=__utma%3d.1675621744.1591667140.64981.1591667140.64981.1591667140.64981.1%3b%2b&utm_source=TestSource&utm_medium=TestMedium&utm_campaign=TestCampaign

I see the hit but it shows with a medium of "(none)" and source of "(direct)" when I'm expecting to see "TestSource" / "TestMedium"... Is it that I'm constructing the URL wrong or a miss in GA setup?

I've also tried putting the utm_source/campaign/medium as part of the utmp address as query string values but no luck: https://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmdt=ShortUrl+Redirect&utmr=0&utmp=/3f20118?utm_source=TestSource&utm_medium=TestMedium&utm_campaign=TestName&utmac=UA-9999999-99&utmcc=__utma%3d.29260146.1591743271.10202.1591743271.10202.1591743271.10202.1%3b%2b

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have to add utm parameters to the querystring of website URL.

Comment: Based on what I understood from your response I now have the following URL, but it isn't working either:

http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmdt=ShortUrl+Redirect&utmp=/3f20118-1?utm_source=TestSource&utm_medium=TestMedium&utm_campaign=TestName&utmac=UA-9999999-99&utmcc=__utma%3d.1484720467.1591725587.26632.1591725587.26632.1591725587.26632.1%3b%2b

Any chance you could provide an example?